# mod_rewrite http://localhost/home/ or http://localhost/home to home.php

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've got a really simple question.
I want to redirect all requests to http://localhost/home/ and http://localhost/home to home.php

My `.htaccess` file contains:

```
RewriteRule ^home/$ home.php [L]
```

which only works for http://localhost/home/

How can I make it work without the `/`in the url too? Is it possible to do it in one line, as opposed to two separate lines such as:

```
RewriteRule ^home/$ home.php
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php
```